# Please specify valid OpenAPI specification file

Tags: azure-api-management

I just created an new API Management Service.
I am following [the tutorial instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-and-publish)

[image]

I am copying the value

```
http://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net?format=json
```

straight from the tutorial. Why is it not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a false warning. Clicking Create does work.

Comment: Not anymore. I can click what I want, the error won't be ignored. - Downvoted

Comment: Sometimes it works and sometimes it won't.. Not sure how Azure validating the Open API Specs..

Comment: No, this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

At the end of my frustration with the same, I copied the contents of the generated swagger.json file into Notepad and saved as swagger.json on my Desktop. Skipped the validation url for a file upload option and was able to Create.

All seems to work fine now.......I don't know..........I just don't know........

Followed through and it appears DNS related:
$ ping https://weatherdataapi157e60163e.azure-api.netping: https://weatherdataapi157e60163e.azure-api.net: Name or service not known

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.